# i want to extract dataframe that meet certain conditions using python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I call Excel data with the tuples Time, Name, Good, Bad using python and pandas.

I want to reprocess dataframe to another dataframe that meet certain conditions.

In detail, i would like to print out a dataframe that stores the sum of Good and Bad data for each Name during the entire time.

please help me anybody who knows well python, pandas.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kG4A.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First aggregate `sum` by [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), change columns names by [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html), add new column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and last convert index to column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Name':list('aaabbb'),
         'Bad':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'Good':[5,3,6,9,2,4]
})
df1 = (df.groupby('Name')['Good','Bad']
         .sum()
         .add_prefix('Total_')
         .assign(Total_Count = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  Name  Total_Good  Total_Bad  Total_Count
0    a          14          9           23
1    b          15          8           23
```

Comment: @mayhaha - oops, there was `typo` in `assign`, now changed to correct answer.

Comment: thank you very very much!! can i adding a Bad_Percent index?(Good_Percent = Total_Bad / Total_Count * 100)

Comment: i find the answer!! thank you! .assign(Percent = lambda x: (x.Total_Bad / x.Total_Count * 100))

Comment: @mayhaha - Super, it should be in one assign also like `.assign(Total_Count = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1), Percent = lambda x: (x.Total_Bad / x.Total_Count * 100))`

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas NamedAgg with `eval`,

```
df.groupby('Name')[['Good', 'Bad']]\
  .agg(Total_Good=('Good','sum'),
        Total_Bad=('Bad', 'sum'))\
  .eval('Total_Count = Total_Good + Total_Bad')
```

Comment: awesome,, you are very clever!

Comment: if i adding a Bad_Percent index? (Good_Percent = Total_Bad / Total_Count * 100)

Comment: i find the answer! thank you!! .assign(Percent = lambda x: (x.Total_Bad / x.Total_Count * 100))